# Understanding inheritance in practice. Printing values of an instance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, printing, instances

I have a class of Agents with a working `__str__` method.
I have a class of `Family(Agents)`.
The `Family` is structured as a dictionary with the Agent ID as key.
After allocating agents to families, I iterate over `my_families`:
When I print `members.keys()`, I get the correct keys.
When I print `members.values()`, I get a list of instances

But, I cannot access the values themselves inside the instances.
When I try to use a method `get_money()` I get an answer that Family class does not have that method. Any help?

```
for family in my_families:
    print family.members.values()
```

Thanks

Providing more information.
Family class

```
class Family(agents.Agent):
"""
Class for a set of agents
"""
    def __init__(self, family_ID):
        self.family_ID = family_ID
        # _members stores agent set members in a dictionary keyed by ID
        self.members = {}

    def add_agent(self, agent):
        "Adds a new agent to the set."
        self.members[agent.get_ID()] = agent
```

Class of agents

```
class Agent():
    "Class for agent objects."
    def __init__(self, ID, qualification, money):
        # self._ID is unique ID number used to track each person agent.
        self.ID = ID
        self.qualification = qualification
        self.money = money

    def get_ID(self):
        return self.ID

    def get_qual(self):
        return self.qualification

    def get_money(self):
        return self.money

    def __str__(self):
    return 'Agent Id: %d, Agent Balance: %d.2, Years of Study: %d ' (self.ID, self.money, self.qualification)

#Allocating agents to families

def allocate_to_family(agents, families):
    dummy_agent_index = len(agents)
    for family in families:
        dummy_family_size = random.randrange(1, 5)
        store = dummy_family_size
        while dummy_family_size > 0 and dummy_agent_index >= 0 and (dummy_agent_index - dummy_family_size) > 0:
            family.add_agent(agents[dummy_agent_index - dummy_family_size])
            dummy_family_size -= 1
        dummy_agent_index -= store
```

Finally the printing example that gets me instance objects but not their values

```
for family in my_families:
    print family.members.values()
```

Comment: Can you also post the Family class code?

Comment: You need to provide more information (i.e., a minimal working example of your class definition) or your question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: Please provide more info, like said before a minimal working example, so we can reproduce your error and test how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see `get_money()` defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: I think it was only a problem of printing after all:  `for family in my_families:
    print family.members.keys()
    for key in family.members.keys():
        print family.members[key].get_ID(), family.members[key].get_money()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Family` is supposed to contain `Agent` objects, why does it inherit from `Agent`? Regardless, you never initialized the parent `Agent` object in the `Family` class's `__init__`, and according to your edit the `get_money` method is contained in the `Agent` class, so `Family` objects don't have a `get_money` method. To access that, you would need to first access a `Family` object's `members` dictionary, then use a key to access the desired `Agent` object, then access that object's `get_money` method.

Comment: Thats it. I had not initialed again. And I had also not used the correct key iteration. Now it is ok. Thanks @TigerhawkT3 . I would vote up, but I lost reputation with this question :( Sorry. I'll be more generous when explaining my questions in the future.